# How to use Angular $scope.variable from controller 1 in ng-class of div using controller 2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-controller, angular1.6

I have 2 controllers boxController.js and homeController.js. On box.html page I initialize the boxController.js. Now, I need to use ng-class on box.html page but the variable I need to use inside ng-class is in homeController.js

I have tried service and factories but these return variables that can be shared across multiple controllers. I am somehow confused about using a shared variable inside html, not inside the controller.

```
**** homeController.js ****

$scope.defaultState = false;
$scope.submitNow = false;

$scope.default = function () {
    $scope.defaultState = !$scope.defaultState
}

$scope.defaultToggle = function () {
    $scope.submitNow = !$scope.submitNow
}

**** box.html (This page uses boxController.js, not homeController.js) ****


// I need to use $scope.submitNow and $scope.defaultState variables in the ng-class of this div

<div ng-controller="boxController" class="ui" ng-class="{'two.column.grid' : submitNow, 'one.column.grid' : defaultState}">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some ways to do that

1. use **$rootScope**
2. use **$watch**
3. create a **shared context** using **factory**

Answer (score 0):

Just adding to @ChickenSoups' answer you can also use `$on` and `$broadcast`. you would do this in the `homeController.js`

```
$scope.defaultState = false;
$scope.submitNow = false;


$scope.default = function () {
    $scope.defaultState = !$scope.defaultState;
   $rootScope.$broadcast('some-event', { defaultState: $scope.defaultState, submitNow:  $scope.submitNow});
}

$scope.defaultToggle = function () {
    $scope.submitNow = !$scope.submitNow;
    $rootScope.$broadcast('some-event', { defaultState: $scope.defaultState, submitNow:  $scope.submitNow});

}
```

and in your `boxController.js` you can catch this event like the following:

```
$scope.$on('some-event', function(event, args) {

    $scope.defaultState = args.defaultState;
    $scope.submitNow = args.submitNow;

});
```

Comment: Thanks! I got it working but there's an unusual problem .Do you have any idea why this happens and how this can be fixed? 

The default ng class works fine as in it adds 'two column grid' in the right order but on the or condition it doesn't add the classes in the right order.

    one column grid

Is added as ...

    column grid one

Comment: @wibwaj Just so you know my superpower is answering questions with the detail of the issue and not telepathy. so if you could also tell me what the `unusual problem` is, that would be great and I will be able to help you.

Comment: Lol sorry I hit enter for line break but that submitted my text. I eventually updated my post. Please check again!

Comment: @wibwaj I don't see an `OR` condition anywhere in your code ? what are you trying to achieve? (Also I would suggest that you close this question and create another question with your current problem as this question is not related to the current problem)

Comment: done! Can you check this out? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57935040/angular-1-ng-class-doesnt-work-as-expected