# Angular 1 ng-class doesn't work as expected

Tags: angularjs, ng-class, angular1.6

I have a simple ng-class that switches two classes based on the condition. When the class is switched, the order of the classes is messed up not sure why. Has anyone a solution for this?

```
<div class="ui" ng-class="{'two column grid' : submitNow, 'one column grid' : defaultState}"></div>
```

Rendered HTML when submitNow is true. This works as expected

```
<!-- submitNow is true -->
<div class="ui ng-scope two column grid"></div>
```

Rendered HTML when defaultState is true. This messes up the order of classes added by ng-class

```
<!-- defaultState is true -->
<div class="ui ng-scope column grid one"></div>
```

*** Edit ****

Quite strange because it works on jsfiddle. But here's the screenshot of my rendered html code

[image]

Here is a demo

https://codepen.io/vibwaj/pen/KKPBdNp

Comment: can you create a plunkr ? also can you tell me why both classes have spaces in them ?

Comment: I tried and tested. it works as you expect. Check jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/varit05/y5xLs9jq/

Comment: Order of classes shouldn't make any difference. Why do you think it matters?

Comment: @charlietfl the rendered html makes me think so. Please see my edited post

Comment: What does *"makes me think so"* mean? None of this is defining a specific problem. Order of classes on an element is not critical for css rules to work

Comment: Its simple right? `<div class="ui" ng-class="{'one column grid' : chatroomExpanded, 'two column grid' : !chatroomExpanded}"></div>` should output either `<div class="ui one column grid"></div>` or `<div class="ui two column grid"></div>` but in my case the output for the latter is `<div class="ui column grid one"></div>`. And this is what _"makes me think so"_ that order of classes is important and I've posted the question here on SO to get some help on it.

Comment: You haven't answered why you think the order is important. Is the css not working as expected? It should be. As to why it's not in same order - that could be done by browser ... note they are in alphabetical sort order

Comment: The css without the right order is not working as expected. It only works as expected when the order is right as in `"ui one column grid"` works but `"ui column grid one"` doesn't work

Comment: Not sure why it's not working. Works fine changing order in a simple example here https://jsfiddle.net/pvw96dmh/ Provide a runnable [mcve] that demonstrates the issue

Comment: Yeah, breaking my head. Not sure either but it just doesn't work. I'm using semantic-ui framework for CSS. Regardless, the purpose behind posting this question was to figure out why ng-class output is not in the same order as in the original ng-class HTML code

Comment: Create a demo that includes the semantic ui css. Hard to help without being able to inspect the issue in browser dev tools. Not sure if it is angular or the browser that is sorting the classes

Comment: @charlietfl pls check it out

https://codepen.io/vibwaj/pen/KKPBdNp

Answer (score 0):

OK...looking at the style rules in elements inspector,  semantic ui uses selectors like `.ui[class*="two column"].grid > .row > .column`

Not sure why they do it that way which is unusual and does make the order important.

Also not sure if it is angular or the browser that sorts the order of those classes. I suspect it is the browser, but that is a guess.

Rather than try to figure out what causes the sort you can add the following rule to fix layout for non specific class order.

```
.ui.two.column.grid > .row > .column, 
.ui.two.column.grid > .column:not(.row){
  width:50%!important;
}
```

[**Working codepen**](https://codepen.io/charlietfl/pen/gOYjPXr?editors=1111)

Comment: this solution doesn't fix the underlying problem. As you can see here, an extended version of the demo with enhanced UI provides broken results. I suppose the only thing that can solve this problem is the specific class order

https://codepen.io/vibwaj/pen/KKPBdNp

Comment: Tried a few things like `class="ui {{getClass()}} "` and still runs into sort issue.  Might resolve it with custom directive template

Comment: Yeah I've even tried js variables `$scope.switchClass = 'one ' + 'column ' + 'grid';` and despite the use of `+` operator it still messes up the order of classes

Comment: I really don't suggest to use the `!important` if there is other alternatives. You can check this: https://uxengineer.com/css-specificity-avoid-important-css/

Comment: @yazantahhan that article  is referring to very general use case ... this is far more specific and is simply trying to set same property as in the framework. The problem is the way the framework selectors use specific order which is noted is very strange

Answer (score 0):

### Update:

I didn't notice the semantic UI framework that is using this approach.
If you still need the same approach, you can check [the forked Codepen](https://codepen.io/yazantahhan/pen/jONXqQG) which I created a custom directive to be alternative than the original NgClass directive.

```
app.directive("myNgClass", function() {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.$watch(
        function() {
          return attrs.isExpand;
        },
        function(isExpand) {
          element.removeAttr("class");
          if (JSON.parse(isExpand)) {              
            element.addClass("two column grid");
          } else {
            element.addClass("one column grid");
          }
        }
      );
    }
  };
});
```

---

### Original Answer

So diving deep into the NgClass directive implementation in Angularjs source code and checking how they update the classes, there is a function called [updateClasses](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngClass.js#L52). 
In this function, it finds which classes should be removed and added.

Instead of replacing all the classes when the Boolean flag gets inverted, NgClass keeps the overlapping classes and checks which classes should be added / removed.

So in your case,`one column grid` (the default case) and `two column grid` have the `column grid` classes in common, so it will keep them, but remove the `one` from the start and add `two` at the end. So the result will be `column grid one`.

I really don't suggest to use the order of the classes as CSS selectors. This will make it more harder to select elements and make things more complex.

I also have a comment regarding the CSS selectors that you are using. I really suggest you to read [Keep your CSS selectors short](https://csswizardry.com/2012/05/keep-your-css-selectors-short/) article so you can have a better practice of using shorter selector and why keeping the CSS selectors short can help with many things.

For example, If you don't need the `one`, `column` and `grid` classes seprately, you can just use `.one-column-grid` as a class name / CSS Selector instead of `.one.column.grid`.

Comment: You aren't recognizing that those classes are predefined by semantic ui css framework. OP is only following their convention

Comment: @charlietfl You're right, sorry about the confusion. Will edit the post

Comment: No need to do `angulr.element(element)` ... the `element` is already a  jqLite object